IMCE button in the URL tool
Months ago, I somehow enabled the IMCE button to appear when adding an URL using CKEditor 5 on Drupal 9.

The problem is that I totally forgot how I enabled that. I already checked CKEditor5's settings within "content authoring," but I don't find any setting to make the button shown in the screenshot appear/disappear.
How can I remove the IMCE button from the CKEditor 5 URL tool?

I found it, it was an edit in: /modules/imce/js/plugins/ckeditor5.js
You go into line 27 and replace the LinkUI's "if" with this to make the IMCE button appear.
// Link.
if (plugins.has('LinkUI')) {
  const view = plugins.get('LinkUI').formView;
  if (view) {
    const el = view.urlInputView.fieldView.element;
    imceInput.processCKEditor5Input(el, 'link');
  }
}

